# css simple layout with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hi there I am trying to achive the following look for a partial UI section of my application,

[image]

As you can see I too buttons centered in the middle of an element with a nice space between them, I have tried to achive this with the following code

```
<div class="modal__footer">  
    <a class="button button--cancel>Skip</a>  
    <a class="button button--confirm>Take the tour!</a>  
</div>

.modal__footer {
    margin-top:30px;
    display:flex;
    .button {
        flex:1;
        &:first-child {
            margin-right:30px;
        }
    }
}
```

However this has resulted in the following,

[image]

As you can I have the buttons in the element but they take up the full width of the parent elements width instead of being centered.

Comment: so add to this button width:some value, for example a{ width: 200px;}

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the `flex:1` from the buttons and use `justify-content:center` on the parent.

```css
.modal__footer {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.modal__footer .button {
  background: #c0ffee;
  padding: 1em;
}
.modal__footer .button:first-child {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal__footer">
  <a class="button button--cancel">Skip</a> 
  <a class="button button--confirm">Take the tour!</a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.modal__footer {
    margin-top:30px;
    display:flex;
    text-align:center;
    .button {
        &:first-child {
            margin-right:30px;
        }
    }
}
```